# Side by side divs, equal heights, IE7+

Tags: css, layout, css-float, html, semantic-markup

I am trying to avoid using layout table in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWyV9/), and I need to come up with more semantic and generic markup plus CSS.

There is an image in the left column and description in the right column.

There are few challenges, however: we don't know any pixel dimensions, and description may be quite long, which is why we cannot simply float two divs side by side.

Image also needs to be vertically aligned, but we don't know container height or image size.

Display: table is not an option. Javascript is not an option

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td class="image">
        <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">
    </td>

    <td class="description">
        <p>Left section only needs to be as wide as image is, and we don't know pixel size of the image. It has to be vertically centered.</p>

        <p>Right section should take all available space left</p>

        <p>We do not know how much text will be in the right section.</p>            
        <p>We can not use display: table since solutions needs to work in IE7 as well</p>                        
    </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Please throw any ideas:)

Comment: Do images must be shown in it's real dimensions?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem, we can't make any assumptions about image size.

Comment: Wihout JavaScript this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXfFG/3/

Explanation:

So you have 2 problems: 1) Adjusting the width and height of the 2 columns. 2) Positioning the image vertically.

Solutions:

1) the left column's width will adjust automatically because it will adjust to the its child's (image) width. setting its float property to left will stick the text right next to it. This is fine when the text is shorter than the image, but what if it's longer like you mentioned? then you will get something like this:

[image]

so we need to make the right column behave like a rectangle. Normally you would set the height of the left column to 100% and that would take care of the problem, but that won't work since its parent doesn't have a fixed height. Anyway, setting the overflow property of the right column will take care of this problem.

```
.right {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

2) Setting the image centered vertically is impossible without JavaScript or using a table layout. but here's what you can do: hide the image by setting its visibility to hidden, this way the left column will still take its width. and then set the background image of the parent container to the image and position it left center.

```
.container {
    background:url("http://www.sourcegate.com/images/stackoverflow-logo.png") left center no-repeat;  
}
```

That concludes the non-js, non-table solution, but If somewhere in your heart you want find that you want to give javascript a try, there are a lot of ways of doing it, but this is what I would do: (1 line of code)

​`$(".container").css('padding-left', $('img').width() + "px");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

http://jsfiddle.net/GtEdc/

Comment: Wow! That's really smart - setting overflow to right column and using background-image for centering (though you basically have to repeat yourself by specifying image url twice).
Here is updated fiddle with your solution (it is clear from the picture that you intended to float this image) http://jsfiddle.net/GtEdc/1/

Answer (score 0):

The [YAML CSS Framework](http://www.yaml.de/docs/index.html#yaml-grids) has a solution for this which works in IE7. If you don't want to implement the whole framework, you should be able to get some ideas from their examples (located under the Grids Module in the section Equal Height Grids).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like they are using this [technique](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) to make equal height columns.

Comment: However, to make this work, some width should be specified (as px or as %), which is something I cannot do as I don't now width of image of width of text coming from the backend. In fact, the whole thing should be completely fluid and resize with browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can't consider jQuery here?  Check out how simple this could be if you did.

```
$(".column").height(Math.max($(".image").height(), $(".description").height()));
$(".column").width(Math.max($(".image").width(), $(".width").width()));
```

These 2 lines of code will produce two equal height, equal width columns.  I always hate when I read an answer that ignores the question and here I am doing it.  But this is just BEGGING to be scripted.

Comment: And what happens with this solution when you resize browser window?

Comment: Anyways, I usually consider using Javascript for layout (calculating sizes of things) to be even more ugly than nonsemantic markup such as table layout.
But thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test this in IE7 because I have IE8, but try it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXfFG/1/

I'll get back to you on vertically centering the image because that's another issue that IE has, but it should be as simple as `vertical-align: middle`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://www.sourcegate.com/images/stackoverflow-logo.png" />
    <div class="text">
        <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Lorem ipsum. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. This is filler text. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. Dolor ipsum valorum. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container img
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text
{
    max-width: 50%;
    float: right;
}​
​
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works just fine, however you specify max-width of 50% for each column. In my case, it is perfectly possible to have 100px wide image and 900px wide description (on 1000px wide browser window). I simply don't know what size images will come from backend, and I was wondering if there is generic table-less solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the min-width if you don't know the width coming from the backend.